# ForData pegando formulário vazio

Tags: html, jquery

Boa noite. Estou tentando pegar os arquivos via formData porem está vindo um formulário vazio.

Segue os códigos:

```
<form action="<?=base_url()?>clientes/addNewFile" id="form_addNewImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<div class="row">   
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
            <span class="fileinput-new"><i class="material-icons">add</i> Adicionar Imagens</span>
            <input type="file" id="cliente_fotos" name="cliente_fotos[]" multiple>
            <input type="hidden" name="idCliente" value="<?=$cliente->idCliente?>">      
            <input type="hidden" name="cliente_Cpf" value="<?=$cliente->cliente_cpf?>">       
            <input type="hidden" name="clienteFotos" value="<?=$cliente->cliente_fotos?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="img">
        </span>
    </div>      
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
        <div class="row" id="image_view"></div>                                
    </div>  
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
        <div class="row" id="image_preview"></div>                                
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin '></i> Salvando"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Salvar</button>                            
    </div>      
</div>
```

```
    $('#form_addNewImage').on('submit', function(e)
    { 
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = new FormData(this);
    });
```

Comment: Onde vc está verificando que está vazio? Vai utilizar Ajax?

Comment: Vou utilizar ajax sim. Verifiquei que ele está vazio via console.log(data);

Comment: O console não mostra o conteúdo do FormData, mas o form chega no destino normal.

Comment: Ta blz amigo. Vou testar. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ele não está vazio. Acontece que o console não mostra os valores. Você pode verificar os dados do FormData no console convertendo-o em array:

```
$('#form_addNewImage').on('submit', function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   var data = new FormData(this);
   console.log(Array.from(data));
});
```